# Creating a point at two intersecting lines

Tags: modeling

I need a way to create a vertex on each line where the lines intersect(inside the red circles). The vertexes should not be free-floating. How would I do this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to delete the free floating vertex, then subdivide the edges once (the only edges ones that will be left in the circles after you delete the vertices) and fill in the faces.

Comment: The problem is solved in this scenario but the question that was asked has still not been answered. If the post does not pertain to the question, then he asking a different question in correspondence with the answer. This post needs to be edited to be correct.

The question is a duplicate of 'How can I join the geometry of intersecting faces/planes and then remove parts?' but the answer is answer a question on how to subdivide and fill geometry.